# certificate, provisioning profile etc for my new iOS app

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I have created an iOS app. The app is already in the store. Now, I am creating a new iOS app. I am wondering, what should I change in regard to development **certificate**, distribution **certificate**, **provisioning profile**.

I am reading [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html). It says the following:

> You use the same development and distribution certificates for iOS,
>   tvOS, and watchOS apps.

OK, does it mean for the new app, I can use the same development & distribution certificate as the old app is using? If so, what about provisioning profile? Could someone please clarify all these to me for the new app?

====== Other related questions =====

1. What if the app is developed by other developers, we are in the same team, now I create a new app. Do I need to create new certificate, provisioning profile, etc?
2. If developer A developed an app & distributed to Apple store, then he left the company. Developer B needs to fix the same app and upload to Apple store again. What does developer B needs from developer A? The private key, right?  Other things certificate, provisioning profile from developer B can be used by developer A directly right?

@Shubham Ojha, thanks for your comment below. But I still want to ask the following scenario:  We are several developers in the same company, we have a company Apple developer account. One developer has created the development/distribution certificate, provisioning profile, etc for the first app, then, he left company.

**Now questions are :**

1. For the same app, I need to fix some bugs and release to Apple store again, what do I need to do with those certificate? I think the private key is on that developer's laptop right? Do I have to have that private key in order to release the app?
2. For a new app, what do I need to with those certificates?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same development and distribution certificates for a new app, since the certificates are bound to a developer or any development/distribution team respectively.

Only you need to create a new App Id from the developer portal(member center) and you can select the same developer and distribution certificates while creation of the provisioning profiles.

1. Yes you need to export the certificates from the MAC on which it was created first and the private key is also required for its installation on any other MAC. **But if the employee hasn't submitted that, then you need to create a different signing identity using your Xcode->preferences->accounts->View Details(of Apple ID associated with developer account).** Here you can create the signing identities and export them.

[image]

At below link you will get all your answers with proper step by step documentation, if you still have any doubts feel free to ask.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

2. For a new app also you need the same certificates since certificates are for team/developer and not for a particular app.

Comment: 1. So, I can use the same certificates but need to generate new provisioning profile for new app, right? 2. I updated my post with two more questions, could you please also take a look? Thanks!

Comment: @Leem.fin I have updated my answer for your questions.

Comment: could you please check again my updated question. Thanks.